# why do i get Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value... here's my code:

Tags: xcode, swift, cllocationmanager

Not sure why this isn't working?  any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thnks.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBAction func nowButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mapLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func bookButton(sender: AnyObject) {       
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()        
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.delegate = self

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegionMake(manager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05))
        mapView.setRegion(regionToZoom, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error ?

Comment: In addition to the above are all your `IBOutlet`s connected?

Answer (score 0):

Possible error cause lies in because of this line in `didUpdateLocations` delegate method:

```
let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegionMake(manager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05))
```

You need to create region like below line (replace this line with above line):

```
let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegion(center: manager.location.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)));
```